# How to make an entire page appear Landscape?

Tags: google-data-studio

is it possible to make one or even just all pages appear **Landscape** instead of Portrait?

I'm talking about **pages**, not reports, unlike most of [Report and page layout](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7355651) (which casually mentions "You can customize individual pages in the report by changing their size and background color").

[image: portrait and landscape orientations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why it's undocumented but here's how to do it for **all pages**:

1. **Don't** edit any report.
2. In the top toolbar, click Theme and layout.
3. On the right toolbar, select LAYOUT.
4. Change Canvas Size to a two options of Landscape (4x3 or 16x9) or just custom and choose any size you want.

Here's how to do it for **a single page** (this one is documented but in a way that's very hard to understand):

1. In the top toolbar, click Page and then Current Page Settings.
2. On the right toolbar, select STYLE.
3. Change Canvas Size from Auto (i.e. uses what all pages use) to two options of Landscape (4x3 or 16x9) or just Custom and choose any size you want.

For option 1:

[image: Theme and layout]

[image: Choose LAYOUT]

For option 2:

[image: Manage Page Settings]

[image: Choose STYLE]

For both options:

[image: Choose Canvas Size]

[image: Canvas Size options]